# WPF: Programatically adding ListViewItems that expand to the full width of their containing ListView

Tags: wpf, listview, listviewitem

I have defined a custom ListViewItem contorl in XAML, which we'll call Item.xaml. These custom items are added to a list view using ListView.Items.Add().

How can I add these items so that they will expand horizontally to take up the entire width of their containing ListView? Currently they always remain their original width.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ChrisWue's answer seemed to work but then I noticed that if I had enough ListViewItems to cause the list to scroll horizontally, the items that were invisible before scrolling down did not stretch horizontally.

I found [this MSDN thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/201d8cf3-86c7-407c-b928-cc34df13dec5/) that gives the correct approach:

```
<ListView Name="ListView" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
  <!-- Stretch the contents to match the columns' width: -->
  <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
      <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    </Style>
  </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
  ...
```

Comment: Forget binding to the listview's width (an approach recommended everywhere), THIS is what works.

Answer (score 2):

The `ListView` has a `HorizontalContentAlignment` you need to set to `Stretch`:

```
<ListView HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ... >
```